# I just installed QT in Linux, and there is something about permission denied

Tags: qt, debugging

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPGdH.png)

Please help me, thank you!
you can see the detail in the image.

Comment: I have used  'chmod 777', but it still not work.

Comment: You should provide more details: is this a run-time error? Show us the code of your program. Put code and error text here as text, not as image. Your post needs significant improvement.

Comment: You could use your shell and navigate to the folder where the `test` program resides using the `cd` command. Then list the permissions of the files `ls -l`.
Side note: you should not call your own programs `test` since it can easily collide with the shell builtin of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You are working on an external drive (e.g USB key), I guess as the path start with `/media`. Some Linux systems prevent any executable to be run from external drives.

Try to change your build directory to a directory on your internal HDD.